# How to host a react + nodejs app on github pages?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, web-hosting

I mean I have already run "npm run build" on my react app so do I just host the entire app i.e including the node part as is or should I do something different?

Comment: Build the app to static HTML/CSS/JS.

Answer (score 1):

Github pages host only static html files and does not support any server-side rendering... You can build your react files to static html/css/js, and host on github pages... If you have a server, you might consider other options to host your server, maybe heroku or netlify or some other free platforms